# How can I change widget type dynamicly?

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, draggable

I'm trying to change widget type for a moment, and it's not working and I couldn't solve this problem. My suppose is that when I clicked the widget it should be draggable and it should be drag target while I'm not clicking.

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
        GestureDetector(
            dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
            onVerticalDragStart: (d) {
                c.index.value = 1;
            },
            onVerticalDragUpdate: (d) {
                c.index.value = 1;
            },
            onVerticalDragEnd: (d) {
                c.index.value = 0;
            },
            child: Obx(
                () => IndexedStack(
                index: c.index.value,
                children: [
                    DragTarget(
                        onAccept: (data) {
                            print(data);
                        },
                        builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) =>
                        Container(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 40,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                        )
                    ),
                    Draggable(
                        data: "data",
                        childWhenDragging: Container(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 40,
                            color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 40,
                            color: Colors.amber,
                        ),
                        feedback: Container(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 40,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                        )
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ))
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional statements. in the updated code of you `Obx` is containing conditional statement.if `c.index.value` is zero, it returns a `DragTarget` widget, and if it's 1, it returns a `Draggable` one:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    GestureDetector(
      dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
      onVerticalDragStart: (d) {
        c.index.value = 1;
      },
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (d) {
        c.index.value = 1;
      },
      onVerticalDragEnd: (d) {
        c.index.value = 0;
      },
      child: Obx(
        () {
          if (c.index.value == 0) {
            return DragTarget(
              onAccept: (data) {
                print(data);
              },
              builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) => Container(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Draggable(
              data: "data",
              childWhenDragging: Container(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
              feedback: Container(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

happy coding...

Comment: I'm sorry but this code isn't working, actually it's the same my code.

Comment: no, please pay attention to the condition if (c.index.value == 0) in Obx.

Comment: RxInt index =0.obs; in my getx controller code

Comment: hey, I don't see index =0.obs; in your code.

Comment: it might be about row or stateless widget?

Comment: yes, I think so, by the way please put the complete code of yourself and make me able to help you in a correct way.